# Swift / phone call / check if user wants to call

Tags: ios, swift

I'm using the following code to perform a phone call.

```
    @IBAction func phoneButtonAction(sender: AnyObject) {

    let phone = "tel://123456789"
    let url:NSURL = NSURL(string:phone)!
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url)
    }
```

This Functions instant calls the desired number.
What's the best practise to ask the user if he's sure he wants to call.

Help is very appreciated.

Comment: Present a `UIAlertController` that asks if they want to call or not

Comment: And how do I ask what "addButtonWithTitle" has been clicked?

Comment: `UIAlertController` doesn't have an `addButtonWithTitle:`, that's `UIAlertView` which is deprecated and you shouldn't use.

Comment: Use `telprompt` scheme instead of `tel`.

Comment: yes ok. that does everything I need. feel free to answer so I can check it. thank you

Comment: @maddy would you please answer, so I can check? :)

Comment: @dan or you, please. both of you helped me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As answered by User maddy, telprompt did the trick.

```
@IBAction func phoneButtonAction(sender: AnyObject) {

        let phone = "telprompt://123456789"
        let url:NSURL = NSURL(string:phone)!
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url)
        }
```